# How to trigger an event in Mootools for a specific tag/element with a specific element ID?

Tags: mootools, css-selectors, domready

How to trigger an event in Mootools for a specific tag/element with a specific element ID?

I have this:

```
<a href="youtube-clip...etc" rel="rokbox" id="video_popup" style="display: none;">Video</a>
```

This `rel="rokbox"` means that the element will be used by the Mootools RokBox modal box, but I've hidden the link.

Now, I've added this code:

```
window.onload = function() {
  if(document.readyState == 'complete') {
    // point of execution
    // here I want to trigger the "a" element I've wrote up before
  }
}
```

The code reaches until the "point of execution", when I set a basic alert, or whatsoever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    $('video_popup').fireEvent('click');
});
```

Note the use addEvent/domready, which is the proper method to add a function which must execute once the page is ready.

Comment: The trigger itself is correct, but it requires for the `click` event to be added in the following fashion `el.addEvent('click', fn);`. If you need more help, create a test case of JsFiddle and paste back a link to play with.